# SSMS 2014 "Deploy Database" feature has old SQL Azure settings

Tags: ssms, azure-sql-database

I'm attempting to test-deploy an existing SQL Server 2005 database into SQL Azure using the "Deploy Database to Windows Azure SQL Database" task in SQL Server Management Studio 2014.

[image]

When the wizard launches, it has incorrect (outdated) database settings available:

[image]

SQL Azure no longer uses "Web" and "Business" models, and when I try to perform the deployment it fails with the error message

> The service objective 'Business' specified is invalid. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 40804)

I receive the same error when I attempt to run "Import Data-tier Application" using a .bacpac of my database. The settings are also old for that interface.

It appears SSMS is using an older deployment wizard. How do I correct this?

---

Edit:

I fired up a SQL Server 2014 VM on Azure and tried performing the same task. I observed the VM version of SSMS has a newer version number (right) than my local copy of SSMS (left):

[image]

I see no pending updates from Windows Update, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SSMS 2014 SP1.  That works.  Currently.

Comment: Yep, SP-1 came out April 2015, so this is now the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I wouldn't have been able to find the solution to this problem if you hadn't decided to open the VM on azure and check the version numbers, so thank you!

After I saw your post, I googled "sql 12.0.2430.0" and found a hotfix from microsoft that fixed the problem.

You can find the hotfix [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2999197)

The update added full support for the new Azure SQL database tiers.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have update the way that we do this now
They do not have Deploy Database to Windows Azure any more

You now back up the file and then import the backup on to the azure box
I tried multiple version of SSMS and not in them any more.
Was last in SSMS 2014, where you need SP1 to get the new azure dbd type as WEB etc was retired.

Ref this person same issue
[Same Issue on stack exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64876/deploy-database-to-sql-azure-task-missing)

This is link to what MS says about these new method
[About Data-tier Applications from MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210546.aspx)

> [image]